# How to run coverage for a Python project with src-layout?

Tags: python, coverage.py

My python project is structured in the so called `src`-layout.

```
hyperorg
├── README.md
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── src
│   └── hyperorg
│       ├── content.py
│       ├── exporter.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __main__.py
│       └── reader.py
└── tests
    ├── helper.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── test_content.py
    ├── test_exporter.py
    ├── test_hyperorg.py
    └── test_reader.py
```

I am not able to get `coverage` running for it. How can I do this?

##### What I tried so far

Run `coverage` in the projects root folder just gives me `Nothing to run`.

Or `coverage run ./src/hyperorg` gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/tab-cloud/hyperorg/src/hyperorg/__main__.py", line 6, in <module>
from .content import Content
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: How do you normally run your test suite?  Take that command, and replace "python" with "coverage run".

Comment: @NedBatchelder it's not that simple. I just migrated to src-layout from the adhoc one and couldn't find recommended way to run coverage, hope you can help. In src-layout ideally the test & coverage needs to run on the installed package, not the one in src directory. If you set coverage source to installed package coverage report generates with absolute path of files. Combining those reports from a build matrix is another challenge.

Comment: Seems to be a serious Issue. Shouldn't we [open a report at upstream](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues)? Maybe [this #963](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/963) is about it?

Comment: [This](https://www.willprice.dev/2019/01/03/python-code-coverage.html) resolves all my concerns stated above.

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways of doing that is entering the `src` folder by `cd src` and then running coverage from there as following:

```
coverage run -m unittest discover -s ../tests
```

You can also leverage rcfile (default `.coveragerc`) to specify configurations and change HTML report path to be created outside the src folder as well.